# Require Login Redirect to Login Page

Tags: wp-admin, login

With the following function :

```
function require_login() {
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
           auth_redirect();
        }
    }
```

Which action should be used?

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'require_login');
```

or

```
add_action('get_header', 'require_login');
```

I've always used template_redirect in the past but lately it doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to protected a content, redirect non-logged users is better done as soon as possible.
So, between the 2 hooks in OP `'template_redirect'` is better. But you can also use an even earlier hook, to improve security and performance (by skipping unwanted queries).

[`'wp_loaded'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) for this sort of things is probably the best choice, because is pretty early but user is already set and so can be checked.